# Xcode not enough memory to distribute my app on App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have a new issue when I try to distribute my app on the App Store with Xcode. It doesn't work and I get the following pop-up saying that I do not have enough memory for my apps. When I click on distribute app => IOS App Store => upload, I can see that Xcode takes all the memory when "fetching App Store configuration".

I restarted my computer but nothing has changed. I only have 4GB of RAM on my computer but it used to work a few days ago. What should I do?

Thank you for your help,

Alex

[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with programming or Stack Overflow. If you don’t know how to use a Mac, ask on SuperUser or AskDifferent.

Comment: Hi matt I guess this is a problem related to Xcode, don't you ?

Comment: No I don’t. With only 4GB of RAM anything could have run you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please free some storage if it didn't work try to close unnecessary apps leaving only Xcode running

Comment: I also tried with nothing else than Xcode but it didn't work. It seems that Xcode wants to use a lot more memory than what my computer has.

Comment: If memory not sufficient it will use disk space

Comment: I have deleted a few files on my computer to free some storage, I can distribute my app now :) thank you